# Migration from mcrypt_encrypt() to openssl_encrypt()

Tags: php, openssl

I have forced to migrate from PHP 5.6 to 7.0+, everything is fine except the mcrypt_encrypt(), it was deprecated already as stated in php.net.

Here's my code

```
$json = array(
    'Amount' => $amount
);

$data = json_encode($json);

function encrypt($data, $secret) 
{ 
    //Generate a key from a hash 
    $key    = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true); 
    $data2  = utf8_encode($data); 
    $iv     = utf8_encode("jvz8bUAx"); 

    //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key. 
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8); 

    //Pad for PKCS7 
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'cbc'); 

    //Encrypt data 
    $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data2, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 

    return urlencode(base64_encode($encData)); 
}
```

I want to replace the deprecated lines with openssl_encrypt.

```
function encrypt($data, $secret) 
{ 
    //Generate a key from a hash 
    $key    = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true); 
    $data   = utf8_encode($data); 
    $iv     = utf8_encode("jvz8bUAx"); 

    $method = 'AES-256-CBC';

    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

    $encrypted = base64_encode($iv . $encrypted);

    return $encrypted;
}
```

Error:

> IV passed is only 8 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16
>   bytes, padding with \0

What I am missing?

UPDATE: Adding decryption part

```
 function decrypt($data, $secret) 
    { 
    //Generate a key from a hash 
    $data = urldecode($data); 
    $iv    = utf8_encode("jvz8bUAx"); 
    $key   = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true); 

    // Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key. 
    $key .= substr($key, 0, 8); 

    $data3 = base64_decode($data); 

    return $data4 = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data3, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 

}
```

Comment: I asked a stupid question.  MD5 produces a 128 bit hash.  That means there is hope for you problem.  Im actually still a little confused.  Do you have a DB with the encrypted data that you still need to decrypt and then re-encrypt with the openssl.  Or do you just want to get a working encrypt function going?

Comment: I have no DB for encrypted data, encryption should sent first then API returns encrypted strings to be decrypted on my end (I add my decrypt function above, btw). I just want to replace the deprecated functions with openssl, without changing any in values on it.

Comment: I see a few problems in your code.  For starters in your original functions, your IV's for your encrypt and decrypt are not the same.

Comment: what do you think my problem why I got IV passed is only 8 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0

Comment: Where are you padding your IV?  I don't see that anywhere.  Or is that your error saying padding with 0's

Comment: As I stated above, I just replacing my old functions with openssl, i don't know if im doing this right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184984/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-phpmeter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

So what you are looking for is the `des-ede3-cbc` Openssl algorithm.

A convenient way to get a list of all your openssl algo's that are on your server is to run:

```
 print_r(openssl_get_cipher_methods(TRUE));
```

This will generate a list that makes for a good reference.

It looks like there was a padding issue as well.  Mcrypt adds padding during the encryption routine and the Openssl does not.  So you have to add padding on the encryption side for the Openssl.  We also need to force the no_padding in the openssl functions.

These functions should work for you now.

```
function encryptNew($data, $secret){

  //Generate a key from a hash
  $key    = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);
  $data   = utf8_encode($data);
  $iv     = utf8_encode("jvz8bUAx");

  //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
  $key .= substr($key, 0, 8); //You key size has to be 192 bit for 3DES.

  $method = 'des-ede3-cbc'; //<----Change you method to this...

  //Mcrypt adds padding inside the function.  Openssl does not. So we have to pad the data.
  if (strlen($data) % 8) {

    $data = str_pad($data, strlen($data) + 8 - strlen($data) % 8, "\0");

  }

  $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv); //Force zero padding.

  $encrypted = urlencode(base64_encode($encrypted)); //Added the urlencode.....

  return $encrypted;

}


function decryptNew($data, $secret){

  //$data = base64_decode(urldecode($data));//<--If you have raw data coming in this needs to be commented out. 
  $iv    = utf8_encode("jvz8bUAx");
  $key   = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

  // Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
  $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

  $method = 'des-ede3-cbc';

  return openssl_decrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $iv); //Force zero padding.

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, are you still there?

here's the reason probably why i'm getting still an error, 

In your encrypt function it returns 
tgpzkS8fLTecZl8fpVTh7A%3D%3D 

while in old function it returns
tgpzkS8fLTdh%2BwPvZ90c1g%3D%3D

for the value {"Amount":"0"}

Comment: Hi Joseph, what happen if I add some params in json file? Can I still convert it? Thanks

Comment: You are just converting whatever array you have to a string representation of a JSON object.  So in reality you are just encrypting a string.  The length of the string does not matter.  That being said some encryption methods have a limit to how much they can encrypt at one time.  But I don't see this affecting you.  Just add to what you have and see if it works it works.